# BackgroundWorkers conflicting when downloading a file of the same name, how do I solve that?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I'm making a program that downloads a photo from the internet and saves it to a file called "temp.jpg". My program user `BackgroundWorker` and I have a problem for example, the second time I run the `BackgroundWorker` my program tries to open "temp.jpg" but it's still being using by the first `BackgroundWorker`.

Any advice how to solve this?

A solution could be naming the file by a timestamp or something like that.

To donwload the photo to temp.jpg I'm using

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
try
{
    webClient.DownloadFile(foto, path);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

the problem is that "temp.jpg" is being used by the first `BackgroundWorker`.

Comment: Hi, did you close the file and dispose of the stream and it's reader when you accessed it the first time?

Comment: Consider a better title for your question, and please don't include tags in it. Also, post some code. Otherwise we'll just be *guessing*, and that won't be constructive.

Comment: @adrian well, when the program add the image to the mp3 file it delete temp.jpg

Comment: Is it a possibility that the file is still downloading in the background when you try and access it? Try opening it on the BGW's `RunWorkerCompleted` event, that way you know it will have finished downloading before you try and use it.

Comment: @bridge before background worker ends the file is deleted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

`WebClient.DownloadFile` handles the management of the file stream for you so, this is not a problem with your disposal of stream objects or release of file handles.

You need to ensure that each concurrent call to `WebClient.DownloadFile` is using a unique filename.

Unique temporary file names can be generated by the framework using the [`Path.GetTemporaryFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename.aspx) method.

---

You should ensure you are closing the the files and releasing the handle in you background worker, this is generally achecived with a [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) block around the `IDisposable` file stream.

If you want to download files concurrently i.e. on multiple background workers at once, then each worker will need a unique file name but, if this is a problem for a repeated run of a single background worker, unique names is not the right solution. Hiding the problem by using new unique filenames will just leak resources.

Comment: I deleted the file after using it so I cant close it

Comment: @GonzaloHernandez, if the file is open, you won't be able to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

File access is a major chokepoint.  A timestamp is not a weird solution.

Create your filename with something like:-

```
string outFile = 
  String.Format("temp_{0:dd}_{0:MMM}_{0:yyyy}_{0:hh}_{0:mm}_{0:ss}_{0:fff}.jpg",
    DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: What happens if you start two downloads in the same millisecond? Why is the better than `Path.GetTemporaryFileName` or `String.Format("{0}.jpg", Guid.NewGuid())`?

Comment: Still getting being used by another process, but I check it and all files have different names

Comment: If you start two downloads in the same millisecond, you'd get a file access error ( although I think you knew that ).  If volume really is high enough, then you can construct your filename using additional elements, such as username, or even the result of a call to Random as an extra discriminator will help.  Even so, I prefer my naming approach because you're left with something that can have some semantic meaning.